# Dependance Sequelize

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sequelize.js

I try to use Sequelize .. And I have problems :( . I don't know if I have a conflict with an other npm package ..

Like the [tuto](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started.html#setting-up-a-connection), I did :

```
npm install sequelize --save
npm install mysql2 -- save
```

In my react app, in "sequelizeYes" folder, I did : 
import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize'

```
const seq = new Sequelize('galadat', 'root', '')

seq
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

export default seq
```

In app component, i call the file like this :

```
import('../sequelizeYes')
```

You can see on the picture differents errors in the console..
Do you have an idea ?

[image]

Comment: `import` ? Do you have a build step?

Answer (score 0):

Did you require the module?

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var fs = require('fs');
```

If you shared the lines of code that the errors indicate it might help as well. It looks like several different files are having problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize is a nodejs module intended to be used in your backend. (server-side) It will not work on client-side (with libraries such as React) as it has dependencies to native NodeJS modules as based on your description that is what you're trying to do. If you're working on a web application and use for example express have a look here https://github.com/sequelize/express-example

Answer (score 0):

As @Eric suggests, you should require sequelize on top of your code. So this should work:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
```

If the error persists, you should delete folder "node_modules" and reinstall dependencies using the command "npm install". Also you should make sure all errors are thrown because of sequelize import.

If the error still persists, you should make sure you try to manipulate the models in server-side code, as @archansel and @frenzzy suggest here: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/976
The reason is referenced above by @razakj answer